# What am I doing wrong (Javascript UpdateClock)

Tags: javascript, date, time, nan

I've been trying to make a simple javascript code that displays the time, but when I set the array and attach it to the currentDay it appears as 'NaN' can y'all help me out please? =] Here's the code:

```
function updateTime(){
var currentTime = new Date();
var Wordday = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
if ( hours == 0 )  {
    hours = "0" ? 12 : hours
};
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
};
var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10){
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
};
var day = currentTime.getDay();
var t_str = + Wordday[day] + "&nbsp;" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " ";
if(hours > 11){
    t_str += "AM";
} else {
    t_str += "PM";
};
document.getElementById('time_span').innerHTML = t_str;
}
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

Comment: FYI, control statements don't need semicolon.

Comment: `var t_str = + Wordday[day]` should be `var t_str = Wordday[day]`.

Comment: What is the intention of `hours = "0" ? 12 : hours`? One branch of the conditional will never, ever be used.

Comment: In the interests of teaching a man to fish, I recommend loading the code in any browser with a debug console, sticking a break point in right at the start and stepping through. If you do this the issues (or at least the line the issues occur on) will immediately be apparent.

Comment: @Patashu It makes the clock 12 hours as opposed to 24 hours.

Comment: @user2331568 That might be the intent, but that's not what the line of code does. Hint: Read it very carefully with no pre-conceptions.

Comment: Using *setInterval*, your clock will slowly drift later as it will not run at exactly the specified interval and occasionally skip a second. Better to use *setTimeout* and call the function again just after the next full second, so at the very end do `setTimeout(updateTime, 1020 - currentTime.getMilliseconds());` and start it by just calling `updateTime();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
var t_str = + Wordday[day] +....
```

with

```
var t_str =  Wordday[day] +...
```

Now it is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

One problem is at

```
if (currentTime.getHours() < 12) {
    t_str += "AM";
} else {
    t_str += "PM";
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UC4C8/)